# Laravel4 manage translation in db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, e-commerce, translation

I am using laravel4 to build an e-commerce app (multilingual)

I have added this bundle to manage translation : 
https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable
So when i add a new product i am using default locale to store translation :

```
$products->translate(App::getLocale())->name = 'my product name';
$products->save();
```

I am a little confused how to manage others translation, should i create a ProductTranslationController and use a foreach on all locales available to build text input ?

EN : My product name
FR : blank input
DE : blank input 
etc ..

Ideas are welcome

Thanks,

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to set/get a translation of the current locale (App::getLocale()) you can omit the `->translate(App::getLocale())` part:

```
echo $product->name; // 'my old product name'
$product->name = 'my product name';
$product->save();
```

To assign multiple translations at once, you can use eloquent's `create()` or `fill()` method:

```
$product->fill(Input::get('translations'));

/* Where Input::get('translations') would be defined in the view like this:
 * 
 * @foreach (Config::get('app.locales') as $locale)
 *     {{ $locale }}
 *     {{ Form::text("translations[{$locale}][name]") }}
 * @endforeach
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to find a good way to let the administrator add translations for an entity?

I also use that bundle, the way I've done is it by putting the locale in my URL and detecting it in my routes.php.

Then I've made a switch language button in my admin back end's header so they can easily switch to a different locale. That way they can create an entity in locale 'en' for example, then simply click on switch language to 'nl' while on the entity's edit form and add translated content for the 'nl' locale (without needing any extra controller).

My locale detection in my routes.php looks like this:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);
if(in_array($locale, array('nl', 'zh'))){
    App::setLocale($locale);
} else {
    // fall back to the default locale (en)
    $locale = null;
}


// Locale prefix group without setLocale filter
Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{
    // Language switch
    Route::get('/switch-language/{locale}', array('as' => 'switchlanguage', 'uses' => 'DefaultController@switchLanguage'))->where('locale', '(en|nl|zh)');

// other routes ....

});
```

In switchLanguage I simply replace the old locale in the url with the new one. For example from www.example.com/zh/blabla to www.example.com/nl/blabla

Then in my controller I can assign values to my entity without having to look a the locale nor using the ->translate() method (as the App::getLocale() has already been set to my new locale)

Controller update function would look like this:

```
$article->title = Input::get('title');
$article->save();
```

where title is a translated field, which will automatically be saved in the locale that was set in App::getLocale() in my routes.php

Hopes that sets you on your way.